# Slider not responsive after creating UIView programmatically

Tags: swift, custom-controls, uipangesturerecognizer

I created a `UIView` programmatically and placed a `UIImageView` init using `PureLayout` to constraint the UI.

How ever, I had a slider function attached to the UI and now which was working properly and when I decided to implement the `UIView` programmatically, the slider function does not work. I do not know why but this is what I have been able to do

```
protocol SwipeDelegate: class {
    func swiped(for view: TripView)
}

class TripView: UIView {

    var shouldSetupConstraints = true
    var startingFrame: CGRect?
    weak var swipeDelegate: SwipeDelegate?

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let sliderView: UIView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    let sliderImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        sliderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sliderView.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

        self.addSubview(sliderView)

        sliderImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sliderImage.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-double_right_filled.png")
        sliderImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.width, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)
        sliderImage.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: screenSize.width / 6)

        self.addSubview(sliderImage)

        swipeFunc()
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(shouldSetupConstraints) {

            sliderView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewSafeArea(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, excludingEdge: .bottom)
            sliderImage.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
            sliderImage.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: sliderView, withOffset: 0.0)

            shouldSetupConstraints = false
        }

        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}

extension TripView {

    private func swipeFunc() {

        let swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(acknowledgeSwiped(sender:)))
        sliderImage.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        sliderImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        swipeGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    }

    @objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sliderView = sender.view {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: sliderView)
            switch sender.state {
            case .began:
                startingFrame = sliderImage.frame
                fallthrough
            case .changed:
                if let startFrame = startingFrame {

                    var movex = translation.x
                    if movex < -startFrame.origin.x { movex = -startFrame.origin.x }

                    let xMax = sliderView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width
                    if movex > xMax {
                        movex = xMax
                        swipeDelegate?.swiped(for: self)
                        //                        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                    var movey = translation.y
                    if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                    let yMax = sliderView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height
                    if movey > yMax {
                        movey = yMax

                    }

                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
                }
            default: // .ended and others:
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your acknowledgeSwiped being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at you instance variable names, they replaced by local variables inside acknowledgeSwiped().
Keep your variable names distinct.

```
@objc func acknowledgeSwiped(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if let sliderView = sender.view {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.sliderView) //self.sliderView
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            startingFrame = sliderImage.frame
            fallthrough
        case .changed:
            if let startFrame = startingFrame {

                var movex = translation.x
                if movex < -startFrame.origin.x { movex = -startFrame.origin.x }

                let xMax = self.sliderView.frame.width - startFrame.origin.x - startFrame.width //self.sliderView
                if movex > xMax {
                    movex = xMax
                    swipeDelegate?.swiped(for: self)
                    //                        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                var movey = translation.y
                if movey < -startFrame.origin.y { movey = -startFrame.origin.y }

                let yMax = self.sliderView.frame.height - startFrame.origin.y - startFrame.height //self.sliderView
                if movey > yMax {
                    movey = yMax

                }

                sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: movex, y: movey)
            }
        default: // .ended and others:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                sliderView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using self.view.addSubview(....) completely prevents me from interacting with the main UI

Comment: Thank you so much Champ.